# Twitter sign in page for Android application using Twitter oAuth

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I am using Twitter to sign into my android appliction. The application presently sends the user to this page [image]

but I want that the app sends the user to this page[image]

My Code:

private static Twitter twitter;

private static RequestToken requestToken;

```
private void OAuthLogin() {
    try {
        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACKURL);
        String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
        Log.e("LoginActivity", "authUrl : "+authUrl);

        Intent intent   =   new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                .parse(authUrl));                   
        this.finish();
    } catch (TwitterException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("in Main.OAuthLogin", ex.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Let me know about other alternatives if available for showing the required Login page.

Comment: try below given url instead of authurl - https://mobile.twitter.com/session/new

Comment: using this url sends the user to browser opening the twitter website instead of my application...

Comment: if you wan t to open twitter from your app then you cant change the home page...